# Why inserting DateTime to MySQL in C# is getting an error?

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

I Try to insert to MySQL database in C#, but what i got is this error

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your Mysql server version for the right syntax to use
>   near "insert (NoNota, Nama, Tanggal, Tipe, Keterangan) VALUES ('1111',
>   'Kickass', '201"  at line 1

i think the problem is the DateTime, in my database datatype i set it to DATETIME, Here is my code

```
        string sqlQuery;

        sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO insert (id, Name, Date, Type, Notes) VALUES ('1111', 'Kickass', '2013-09-09', 'Cash', 'Nothing')";


        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlQuery, connect);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            CloseConnection();
            MessageBox.Show("Operation INSERT is SUCCESS!!");
        }
```

What's wrong with it? i try excute my SQL Queries it work very FINE in MySQL Workbench, it automatically convert the DateTime and insert it into the table. Any clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

insert is a reserved word (INSERT INTO insert).  Rename the table or escape with backticks.  I'd highly recommend renaming.

Comment: Ooh! god! ty! Where i can find restricted word for mysql Syntax?

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape [reserved words in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) like `INSERT` with backticks

```
INSERT INTO `insert` (id, Name, ...
            ^------^---------------------here
```

But it would be way better to rename your table. `insert` does not say anything about your data. Try to think of its content. When you have hundreds of tables in a database you need to name every one very carefully to keep track what it contains.

When you name your column, name it after the single word that finishes this sentance:

> The data of my table holds ...